# javascript classes why doesnt second parameter getter work below

Tags: javascript, class, setter, getter

Why is my getter for second parameter returning `undefined` in the code segment below? It works fine for the age parameter but not for height. If you access it with _param all is well as you can see from the output below:

```
class Person {
    constructor(myage, myheight){
        this.age = myage;
        this.height = myheight;
    }

    get age(){
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(myage){
        this._age = myage;
    }

    get height(){
        this._height;
    }

    set height(myheight){
        this._height = myheight;
    }
 }

 var p = new Person(10, '5 feet');
 console.log(p);

 console.log(`age = ${p.age} and height = ${p.height}`);
 console.log(p.height);
```

Generates value correctly for age but not height

```
 bash-3.2$ node classes.js
 Person { _age: 10, _height: '5 feet' }
 age = 10 and height = undefined
 undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a `return` in the `height` getter:

```
get height(){
    return this._height;
}
```